# C Declare and define quickly the fields of an array

Tags: arrays, c, variables, embedded

I have a struct that contains a field that is an array of 7 cells and I want to define the values of the cells quickly and easily.

Is there a way to easily and quickly declare and define an array such as with this manner ?

```
struct my_struct
{
   uint8_t array[7];
}

struct my_struct var = {0};

memcpy(var.array, (uint8_t){0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, 7);
```

Or this way ?

```
struct my_struct
{
   uint8_t array[7];
}

struct my_struct var = {0};

var.array = (uint8_t)[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Or I must do this way ?

```
struct my_struct
{
   uint8_t array[7];
}

struct my_struct var = {0};

var.array[0] = 0;
var.array[1] = 1;
var.array[2] = 2;
var.array[3] = 3;
var.array[4] = 4;
var.array[5] = 5;
var.array[6] = 6;
```

Thank you ;)

Comment: Check this out also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards

Comment: If you want to init all array members to the same value you can use memset

Comment: @GabrielT I've read that but it seems that memset() work only for variables of 1 bytes (char, uint8_t, short).

Comment: @Amaury memset is for n bytes if your array is 4 bytes long you put 4 in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var.array = (uint8_t)[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Do you mean a compound literal?

then the syntax is `(uint8_t [])` instead of  `(uint8_t)[]`

But you can not assign to an array ([Why are arrays not lvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058377/why-are-arrays-not-lvalues)).

Your first example is almost correct:

```
memcpy(var.array, (uint8_t){0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, 7);
```

but again, use the correct syntax:

```
memcpy(var.array, (uint8_t []){0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array and struct initializers can be nested:

```
struct my_struct var = { {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} };
```

Comment: This could be the right answer, but I assumed they wanted to fill in the array dynamically, not when the variable is declared.

Comment: @Barmar Nope. I wanted to do it statically.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Your first attempt was close, but the type specification is missing the `[]` that make it an array type.

```
memcpy(var.array, (uint8_t[]){0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, 7);
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm looking for !
Side question: When declaring an array this way. Where is stored (uint8_t[]){0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, in the stack or as a global variable ?

Comment: From the [spec](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5): **If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.**